# Traceback when configuring hgweb.cgi to serve Mercurial repositories

Tags: configuration, mercurial

I am having trouble having my `hgweb.cgi` script successfully read my `hgweb.config` file. It fails with the error `Abort: /var/www/hg/hgweb.config: not a Mercurial bundle file`. Details below

**/var/www/hg/hgweb.config**

```
[collections]
/ = /home/danish/repos/hg/

[web]
baseurl = /hg
style = git-web
```

**Error Details**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hgweb.cgi", line 17, in &lt;module&gt;
    application = hgweb(config)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/hgweb/__init__.py", line 12, in hgweb
    return hgweb_mod.hgweb(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/hgweb/hgweb_mod.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.repo = hg.repository(u, repo)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/hg.py", line 63, in repository
    repo = _lookup(path).instance(ui, path, create)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/bundlerepo.py", line 303, in instance
    return bundlerepository(ui, repopath, bundlename)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial/bundlerepo.py", line 175, in __init__
    raise util.Abort(_("%s: not a Mercurial bundle file") % bundlename)
Abort: /var/www/hg/hgweb.config: not a Mercurial bundle file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out. I was using an old version of Mercurial with the latest merged hgweb.cgi script. The standard install of Mercurial on my Ubuntu 10.04 comes with a version that like 4 releases behind.

Once I upgraded my Mercurial, it started working.